# Why are all my results 0?

Tags: python

I'm doing rounded-integer batch conversion of Fahrenheit to Celsius (yes, for codeabbey.com), and I've spent hours on this to get stuck in something that looks like it should run smoothly. Specifically, my results are all zero. So somewhere in the `for` loop, probably in the assignment of `j` and `k`, the math is breaking down. I've looked at it again and again. Why am I getting zeroes in my results?

```
fahrenheit = raw_input().split() # Dump copy-and-pasted values into a list.
iter = int(fahrenheit.pop(0)) # Remove the first value and use it as a counter.

celsius = [] # Make an empty list for results.
x = 0 # Index counter 

for i in fahrenheit:
    j = (int(i)-32) * (5.0/9)
    k = (int(i)-32) * (5/9)
    if float(j) == k:
        celsius.append(j)
    elif j > 0: # For positive results
        if (j - k) >= 0.5: # If integer value needs +1 to round up.
            celsius.append(k+1)
        else:
            celsius.append(k)
    elif j < 0: # For negative results
        if (k - j) >= 0.5:
            celsius.append(k+1) # If integer values needs +1 to bring it closer to 0.
        else:
            celsius.append(k)
    else:
        celsius.append(k) # If the result is 0.

print ' '.join(celsius)
```

The formatting of the data calls for this strange setup. The first number in the data is not a temperature to test. All others are. So `5 80 -3 32 212 71` calls for five calculations: 80, -3, 32, 212, and 71 converted to Celsius.

Comment: Integer division: `5/9 == 0`

Comment: ...D'oh! I can't believe I looked at that thing so long and never realized it. Thanks for pointing it out to me!

Comment: You may get the right result by removing the parentheses  the around `5/9`. Without them, the multiplication by 5 will happen before the division.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Peter Wood in his comment, `5/9` evaluates as 0 due to integer division. However, the rest of your program could be simplified by using Python's built in [round](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function.

```
>>> [round(x) for x in [26.0, 26.4, 26.5, 26.9]]
[26.0, 26.0, 27.0, 27.0]
```

You can then rewrite like:

```
celsius = [int(round((f-32)*5.0/9.0)) for f in fahrenheit[1:]]
```

Comment: Way cool. Thanks. I can't wait until I've learned enough that I can condense my code into such efficient lines. Gotta keep pluggin' away, bit by bit!